# orbd equivalent in GlassFish CORBA / Start GlassFish ORB

Tags: java, glassfish, corba

I try to migrate from JDK8 to JDK11. So I use glassfish-corba as replacement for the CORBA implementation, which is not shipped anymore with JDK11.

I found the [GlassFish IDL Compiler](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.corba/idlj) as executable JAR file in a Maven Repository.
However, I cannot find an orbd equivalent from GlassFish. I think the ORB implementation is part of the GlassFish Server, which seems to be maintained by Eclipse now and can be found [here](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/downloads). There is little documentation on how to [Administering the Object Request Broker (ORB)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24928/orb.htm#GSADG00018) using the GlassFish Server.
However, it does not seem to work for me.

I did Oracle's [Hello World tutorial for CORBA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/idl/jidlExample.html). I compiled the IDL file using idlj-4.2.1.jar from the maven repo linked above. Now my code compiles and works when I start the JDK8 ORB, e.g. `orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050`.
But it does not work when I start the GlassFish Server, even though I created an  IIOP Listener as described by the linked documentation above:

```
asadmin.bat create-iiop-listener --listeneraddress localhost --iiopport 1050 sample_iiop_listener
asadmin.bat start-domain --verbose
```

How do I start an ORB using GlassFish that accepts CORBA connections?

Comment: Earlier I was using Jacorb implementation and I can not find the equivalent of "org.jacorb.naming.NameServer" in glassfish CORBA implementation.